# getting datetime from python string when tzinfo is present

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

[I have found answers to question like this one helpful but not complete for my problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010945/gae-howto-get-date-from-form-request)
I have a form where the user automatically produces a date. I would like to store that as a date time.

I don't need any of the information after the seconds, but I cannot find a datetime.datetime.strptime code to translate the remaining stuff. So I would either like a strptime code that works for python2.7 on google app engine, or a string editing trick for removing the extra information that is not needed.

date-from-user='2012-09-22 07:36:36.333373-05:00'

Comment: Are you sure discarding the time zone information is a good idea...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice your string to only select the first 19 characters:

```
>>> datefromuser='2012-09-22 07:36:36.333373-05:00'
>>> datefromuser[:19]
'2012-09-22 07:36:36'
```

This let's you parse the date without having to bother with the microseconds and timezone.

Do note that you probably *do* want to parse the timezone too though. You can use the [`iso8601` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/) to handle the *whole* format, without the need to slice:

```
>>> import iso8601
>>> iso8601.parse_date(datefromuser)
datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 22, 7, 36, 36, 333373, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '-05:00'>)
```

The `iso8601` module is written in pure python and works without problems on the Google App Engine.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but the `import iso8601` requires the pypi library or something which I do not know how to install on the appengine.

Comment: @zerowords: PyPI is the Python Package Index; it points you, or a tool like `pip`, to where you can download the package. Just download the package from the link I provided you. Install it like any other python library, with your project.

Comment: Martijn, I have never installed a library, and when I download from that link I get an egg, which I have not encountered. Could you please bring me up to date (a pun)?

Comment: @zerowords: Grab the `.tar.gz` archive instead of the egg.

Comment: I don't see a `.tar.gz` at the link you sent.

Comment: At the bottom of the page: http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/i/iso8601/iso8601-0.1.4.tar.gz#md5=f63c17a1786b9fe48d05b43d61970f85

Comment: Ok, I apologize that I could not see the `.tar.gz`. I have placed the unzipped download into the `scheduler` subdirectory that I created for it as follows.  `scheduler/static/lib/iso8601-0.1.4/iso8601/iso8601.py` Now how do I fix app.yaml so that I can `import iso8601` ?

Comment: Remove the `iso8601-0.1.4` directory; move it's contents up to `lib`.

Comment: Also see [Installing usual libraries inside Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1166685)

Comment: `ERROR    2012-09-23 11:55:36,067 dev_appserver_main.py:600] Fatal error when loading application configuration:
the library "iso8601" is not supported
  in "/Users/brian/googleapps/scheduler/app.yaml", line 25, column 1`
This is my relevant app.yaml `libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe                                                              
  version: latest 
- name: iso8601
  version: latest`

Comment: You don't need to list it in your app.yaml.

Comment: Maybe I got it right by just adding the file iso8601 to the `scheduler` directory and removing the reference in app.yaml. But I am still getting the error that is in my original question as an update 0. And it is frustrating.

Comment: @zerowords: that's a new problem; put parethesis around your datetime calculation: `logging.info("res-utime: %s" % (res-utime))`

Answer (score 1):

Python Docs would be a good place to start. strptime() would be your best option.

```
import datetime

datefromuser = '2012-09-22 07:36:36.333373-05:00'
datetime.datetime.strptime(datefromuser.split(".")[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

2012-09-22 07:36:36
```

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: `date-from-user` is not a valid python variable. Nor is this a solution to the OP's problem; his input string would raise an exception if you tried to parse it using your format string.

Comment: You're right about the variable, but the OP defined that, so I was reusing it for simplicity sake. As for the exception, it's been fixed.

Comment: I added a revision to the original question to show the follow on error that is now plaguing me.

Comment: In your answer `datetime.datetime` should be `datetime` I believe.`

Comment: That would be true if I used `from datetime import datetime`. Paste the code into your python interpreter.